# Übersetzung von "to appear" im Literaturverzeichnis

Tags: translation, english-to-german

In Literaturverzeichnissen wissenschaftlicher Arbeiten findet man häufig bei bisher unveröffentlichten Dokumenten den Zusatz "to appear" als Notiz. Ich schreibe gerade eine Diplomarbeit auf deutsch und bin mir nicht ganz sicher, was dabei die übliche Ausdrucksweise ist.

Ich würde jetzt sowas wie

- noch nicht erschienen
- noch nicht veröffentlicht

schreiben – oder gibt es da bessere oder üblichere Varianten?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Es ist sicher eine Ausnahme, dass wir in einer wissenschaftlichen Arbeit auf unveröffentlichte Quellen zurückgreifen müssen. Dennoch findet man die nötigen Inhalte derweilen eben nur in unveröffentlichten, oder wenn die Arbeit hochaktuell ist, in noch nicht veröffentlichten Quellen.

Es gibt dafür zwar übliche, aber keinesfalls allgemeingültige Zitierregeln. Hier ist es zumindest ratsam, bei der Fakultät, in der Du Dein Diplom einreichst, nach den dort gültigen Zitierregeln zu fragen. Möglicherweise gibt es sogar strenge Vorgaben, ob und in welcher Form man unveröffentlichte Quellen zitieren darf. Manche sind da sehr restriktiv und fordern, diese als Anhang der Arbeit anzufügen.

Nach dem Stand der unveröffentlichten Arbeit kann man zumindest vier Typen unterscheiden, die man beim Zitieren auch so nennen sollte:

- **unveröffentlicht:** Die Arbeit ist nicht erschienen und wird wahrscheinlich auch nie erscheinen. Dem Zitat kann man die Art der Arbeit noch hinzufügen, damit wird es genauer. ***Beispiel:*** (unveröffentlichtes Manuskript), (unveröffentlichte persönliche Mitteilung)
- **Zur Veröffentlichung vorgesehen:** Die Arbeit ist schon fast fertig und man kann womöglich schon sagen, in welchem Jahr und in welcher Zeitschrift sie erscheinen soll. ***Beispiel:*** (zur Veröffentlichung vorgesehen. J. Better Science, 2013)
- **Zur Veröffentlichung eingereicht:** Die zitierte Arbeit ist fertig und wartet nur noch darauf, von der Zeitschrift oder dem Verlag akzeptiert zu werden. ***Beispiel:*** (zur Veröffentlichung eingereicht. J. Much Better Science 2012)
- **Zur Veröffentlichung angenommen:** der beste Fall, und dann wird die Arbeit auch gut und seriös zitierfähig, da die Publikation nur noch gedruckt werden muss. Man kennt sowohl die Zeitschrift als auch das Jahr, womöglich sogar die genaue Ausgabe. ***Beispiel:*** (zur Veröffentlichung angenommen. J. Takes Everything 99, 2012)

Streng genommen trifft ***"to appear"*** aber nur auf den Fall 2 in der Liste zu, nämlich *"Zur Veröffentlichung vorgesehen"*. Manchmal darf man auch direkt die englische Bezeichnung *"to appear"* übernehmen. Das hängt ganz von der Fakultät ab.

Comment: Erstmal danke für die sehr ausführliche Antwort. Ich kann die betroffene Veröffentlichung am ehesten in Kategorie 4 einordnen. Allerdings handelt es sich hierbei nicht um ein Journal-Paper, sondern um ein Workshop-Paper, das dann in Proceedings veröffentlicht wird. Dann würde ich jetzt also demnach als Notiz dahinter schreiben: "Autor: Titel ... - >Zur Veröffentlichung angenommen<"?

Comment: Evtl. musst Du auch noch schreiben, wo der Artikel angenommen wurde: "Zur Veröffentlichung in den *Proceedings of the 22. Workshop with Alfa* angenommen. 2012".

Comment: Ich hätte das jetzt so gemacht: "Autor: Titel. In: Workshop, Jahr. - Zur Veröffentlichung angenommen". Das wäre für mich einheitlicher. Es wäre wie ein normales Paper, nur mit einem zusätzlichen Kommentar.

Comment: Höre ich da etwa Ironie? :D

Comment: Ich bin gerade auf diesen alten Text gestoßen. Der Text zu Fall 2
"Zur Veröffentlichung vorgesehen" ist irreführend: Man weiß hier
höchstens, wo man den Text *einreichen will* - man weiß definitiv
nicht, ob er dann auch *angenommen* wird, und schon gar nicht, wann
er, falls angenommen, *erscheinen* wird. Im Englischen wäre Fall 1
*"unpublished"*, Fall 2 *"in preparation"*, Fall 3 *"submitted"*,
und Fall 4 *"to appear"* oder *"accepted for publication"* oder, wenn man
die genaue Ausgabe kennt, auch *"in print"*.